# Changing language of flyspell (Emacs) with a shortcut

Tags: emacs, auctex, flyspell

I'm using the following code to launch `flyspell` when I edit LaTeX files with Emacs+AUCTeX.

```lisp
(if (file-exists-p "/usr/bin/hunspell")
    (progn
      (setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
      (eval-after-load "ispell"
        '(progn (defun ispell-get-coding-system () 'utf-8)))))


(global-set-key [f2] 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

You can notice `flyspell` is automatically started when in the LaTeX mode (AUCTeX mode) and could be disable/enable with the shortcut <kbd>F2</kbd>.

The configuration uses `hunspell` (which is much better than `ispell` or `aspell` in my opinion) with the system default language (in my case: French).

I would like to be able to change the language with a shortcut. I'm writing in French and English (sometimes inside the same document) and I would be able to switch language in an quick way during editing. For example, it would be wonderful if I could choose English dictionary with <kbd>F4</kbd> and go back to the default French dictionary with <kbd>F3</kbd> (when <kbd>F2</kbd> is still used to toogle on/off `flyspell`).

P-S : For now, I'm doing the switch with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ispell-change-dictionary` but it isn't very efficient.

Comment: Would you publish, maybe as an edit, your whole setup regarding flyspell, including the dictionary and so on? I'd really be interested, but using only your code throws errors. I found this site: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractiveSpell#toc5 -- I will test what's been published there.

Comment: @KeksDose This is all my flyspell related code. It loads the system default dictionnary but the accepted answer show how to choose another one. Perhaps, hunspell-xx (where xx is the language shortcut : en for English) is not installed on your system?

Comment: @KeksDose you could override the system default dictionnary with `(setq ispell-dictionary "francais")`.

Comment: Thank you. I got a working system with hunspell by using "rw-hunspell.el". The dictionary is far better than a/ispell, at least regarding German language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following code to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(global-set-key
 [f3]
 (lambda ()
   (interactive)
   (ispell-change-dictionary "francais")))
(global-set-key
 [f4]
 (lambda ()
   (interactive)
   (ispell-change-dictionary "english")))
```

Are you already aware of [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Style-Files-for-Different-Languages)?

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of AUCTeX capabilities regarding languages. However, I prefer to use `csquote` and `\enquote{}` command.