# How to set spelling dictionary on the fly in Aquamacs

Tags: emacs, editors, spelling, aquamacs

This is not specifically a TeX question, but I think it might be relevant here since all TeX users are also text editor users.

I use the Emacs Aquamacs (v 3.0a) text editor. My locale on my Mac is Australian. As far as I understand Emacs applies in checking the spelling the current locale of the system is running on. I want to edit a document to be sent in the US and I then would like to change the dictionary from Australian (or British) to American English but just for one document.

I tried to navigate the Aquamacs documentation but without much success. It seems that the default `Flyspell` dictionary in my Aquamacs preferences is `Standard`. I couldn't find any indication to the actual dictionary file Aquamacs is using and how to change it.

EDIT: In my `~/Library/Spelling` I have these dictionaries: `en`, `en_au`, `en_GB`, `es`, `it`, `LocalDictionary`. I can select any of these dictionaries through `Edit -> Spelling -> Change dictionary...` but without any effect in the words identified as wrong by the editor. I still get all US spellings checked as wrong (e.g. "organization", "behavior") but even selecting `en` as dictionary all Italian and Spanish words are not checked as wrong (e.g. `alcalde`, `zorro`, `popolazione`). It seems it is checking against all three dictionaries: british english, italian and spenish but not american english...

Comment: **Spell-Checking**. *Aquamacs spell-checks your documents with the OS X spell-checker, supporting more than a hundred languages and system-wide user dictionaries.*  http://aquamacs.org/features.shtml  Open up `System Preferences` on OSX . . . `Language & Text` and select from the `Language` tab.  The user personal dictionary is stored at: `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary`

Answer (score 2):

You can change the dictionary with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`ispell-change-dictionary`<kbd>RET</kbd>.  It's also possible to select the dictionary using the menu `Tools > Spell Checking > Change Dictionary...`.

In addition, you can specify the spelling language on a per-file basis with the file local variable `ispell-local-dictionary`, whose description (<kbd>C-h v</kbd> `ispell-local-dictionary` <kbd>RET</kbd>) reads

> If non-nil, the dictionary to be used for Ispell commands in this
>   buffer. The value must be a string dictionary name, or nil, which
>   means use the global setting in `ispell-dictionary`. Dictionary names
>   are defined in `ispell-local-dictionary-alist` and
>   `ispell-dictionary-alist`.
>
> Setting `ispell-local-dictionary` to a value has the same effect as
>   calling <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ispell-change-dictionary` with that value.  This variable
>   is automatically set when defined in the file with either
>   `ispell-dictionary-keyword` or the Local Variable syntax.

Thus, for example

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% ispell-local-dictionary: "american"
%%% End:
```

sets the dictionary to be used to `american`.

If you want to create a shortcut to change the dictionary to a specific language see the question [Changing language of flyspell (Emacs) with a shortcut](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166681/31416).  In order to set the spelling dictionary according to the default `babel` language see https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Style-Files-for-Different-Languages.

Comment: I can't seem to find any "american" dictionary though... Indeed I see only one "English" dictionary.

Comment: @Francesco It was just an example, you have to check the dictionaries actually available in your system.

Comment: Aquamacs uses the native OSX spellchecker, which has the user personal dictionary stored at: `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary`  Therefore, the spell check settings of the original poster need to be OS system wide -- open up System Preferences on OSX . . . `Language & Text` and select from the `Language` tab.